# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un programa que intercambie los caracteres de un string de dos en dos?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dev-c++

quiero hacer un programa en el que el usuario introduzca un string y que el programa retorne el mismo string con los caracteres intercambiados de dos en dos.

Esto es lo más cerca que he estado, pero siguen sin ser lo que quiero hacer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string fraseCambiada(string frase)
{
    int longitud = frase.length();
    int i; 
    for (i = longitud; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int lugar = rand()%longitud;
        char tmp = frase[i-1];
        frase[i-1] = frase[lugar];
        frase [lugar] = tmp;
    }
    return frase; 
}

int main()
{
    string frase;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Ingrese una frase: "; 
    getline(cin, frase);

    frase = fraseCambiada(frase);

    cout << frase << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Pon un ejemplo para que se te entienda